# Java: How to take the first word in each line from a text file and write it to a new text file?

Tags: java, exception, try-catch, throws

My prof posted this to practice exception handling and reading and writing to textfiles:

Write a method called `removeFirstWord`

`removeFirstWord` returns an int and takes two strings as arguments.

The first argument is the name of the input file and the second the name of 
the output file.

It reads the input file as a text file one line at the time.  It removed the first word from each line and write the resulting line to the output file.  **sometext.txt** below is an example input file with **output.txt** the expected output file.

If the input file does not exist, the method should throw FileNotFoundException.  If the input file is empty, the method should throw EmptyFileException.  The method should not throw any other exceptions.

If an exception other than `FileNotFoundException` is thrown, the method should return -1.  Otherwise, the method returns 0."

This was his code:

```
    public static int removeFirstWord(String inputFilename, String outputFilename) throws FileNotFoundException, EmptyFileException {
    int lineCounter = 0;
    try {
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFilename));
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outputFilename)));
        String line = input.readLine();
        while (line!=null){
            lineCounter++;
            String[] words = line.split(" ");
            for (int index = 1; index < words.length; index++) {
                String word = words[index];
                writer.print(word + " ");
            }
            writer.println();
            line = input.readLine();
        }
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        input.close();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        return -1;
    }

    if (lineCounter == 0) {
        throw new EmptyFileException();
    }
    return 0;   
}
```

I do not understand why she used an array. Can't you just read the first word and stop at a space and write that word to the output file and jump to the next line?
Also I do not understand the difference between doing a throws `FileNotFoundException`, `EmptyFileException` vs just doing a catch?

Comment: Given that the code already solves the problem, your question might be better suited to our sister site [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: This is a off-topic question for Code Review Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

First thing First- Actually, you are little bit confused with her requirement. Actually, she wants to remove only the all first words of all line from the given text file and remain words will be there in the output file.
So, for this she choose to convert a complete line into an String array. the other possible way was to do substring the given line but that will be costly in time complexity.

Second why she used throws instead a catch block because as per the business requirement the was no use to catch the both exception, she wants to catch it later or wants to show it to the end user.

I think this will help you out.